# Suggestions for supporting a heavy lens?

Tags: lens, camera-straps, monopod, support-equipment

I have just returned to photography after several years in the wilderness, and as such I have invested in some decent lenses straight off the bat this time round.

My main telephoto lens has ended up weighing around the 2kg mark, which I am concerned about hanging off of the camera body unsupported, as its sure to cause connection issues later on in the camera or lenses life.

I can connect either a monopod or a shoulder strap directly to the lens itself via the tripod connector, which solves the issue of support in each individual case, but I cannot connect both at the same time - can anyone suggest a better way of supporting the lens itself, eg is there a strap which somehow connects directly to the lens rather than the lenses tripod mount?

Comment: What *evidence* do you have that this is actually a problem?

Comment: I have no *evidence*, only *suspicions* but I also dont want to generate my own *evidence* with a £1000 lens and £800 body at some point in the future...

Comment: A better question might be whether this is a problem you should be concerned about. Intuitively a heavy lens will put some strain on the connection hardware, but on the other hand this is definitely something that camera designers and engineers will consider when creating the connector. It may be the case that the hardware is tough enough to support all that weight without getting noticeably damaged over time.

Comment: What specific mount is involved here?

Answer (score 1):

Op-Tech's [Lens Loop](http://optechusa.com/lens-loops.html) is one such product that has connectors that allow them to be used with a plethora of [straps](http://optechusa.com/straps.html) they offer. Use of the loop allows a quick release plate to remain attached to the lens' tripod foot.

I have not personally used the Lens Loop myself. I do use the Op-Tech system and have been very happy with both a Canon Professional Services provided neck strap  made by Op-Tech and a double sling. The near endless varieties of system connectors available at very reasonable prices make it very practical to build your own custom rig without breaking the bank.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it still looks like it can put a lot of strain on the lens-camera connector, which is what Im trying to avoid if possible.

Comment: I'm a Canon guy and routinely carry my 70-200 f/2.8 II (1.7kg)  mounted to a body that is attached to a sling via the strap lugs on the camera body. In the near five years I've owned that lens I've not experienced any problems with the bayonet mount on either the lens or the bodies to which it has been attached.

Comment: @Moo the only way to get rid of the strain would be to have a single common support that connects to both: the tripod collar of the lens and the tripod socket of the camera. The fact that not even the 800mm guys are doing this should be a hint that this is not necessary.

Comment: @null with an 800 you would always carry it by the lens. But most guys I know with 400 or heavier lenses tend to leave them attached to a monopod all of the time. The heaviest Canon bodies are only about 1.5kg and all of that is very close to the connection there's never much torque placed on the mount when the lens is fully supported.

Comment: @null And you don't have to use the tripod foot with the big white super telephotos. They all have at least one strap lug attached directly to the lens body. Some have two on opposite sides of the lens.

Comment: To slightly expand on @Michael Clark's answer: For my larger lens I use the Op-Tech connectors - one on the camera, one on the QR plate on the lens. These are both on the sling adaptor produced by Op-Tech. This does eliminate all potential strain on the mount, though this is not why I have adopted this system.

Answer (score 1):

I recently bought myself a [Peak Design Slide shoulder strap](https://www.peakdesign.com/product/straps/slide/). This one is attached to camera or lens with small anchors. I attached two anchors on the lens (one on a Arca-Swiss compatible plate, included with the strap). And I attached to anchors in the middle of the screw of the tripod clamp (I don't know correct english word for that). With this setup, I realy enjoy the freedom while shooting.

I think the question you are asking is not only important to preserve your equipment, but also to have optimal comfort while shooting, special with large and heavy tele lens and frequent switches between free hand and tri/monopod.

My lens is around 3 kg, camera around 0.8 kg and the strap and anchors holds it without any problems doing several walks in the woods for taking pictures of birds.